# can not create docker image with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to make a docker image with mongo installed. But everything works fine except the mongo is not installing. I am running the docker on Mac. The image contains ubuntu 16.0.4. Here is the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7.5-devel
COPY requirements.txt /workspace/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /workspace/requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')" ]

#show the ubuntu version
RUN cat /etc/*release

#mongo installation command

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E52529D4
RUN bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libcurl3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install mongodb-org
RUN systemctl enable mongod.service
RUN systemctl start mongod.service
RUN mongo --version
```

Build log after ubuntu version command (before that seems unimportant for my problem)

```
Step 6/15 : RUN cat /etc/*release
 ---> Running in 24782e276d20
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
Removing intermediate container 24782e276d20
 ---> 00320766b78e
Step 7/15 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E52529D4
 ---> Running in 2ef9e4b20a91
Executing: /tmp/tmp.Z3Rrfg8aCv/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
E52529D4
gpg: requesting key E52529D4 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E52529D4: public key "MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
Removing intermediate container 2ef9e4b20a91
 ---> 1fe0c89be2f0
Step 8/15 : RUN bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list'
 ---> Running in e33ec803a371
Removing intermediate container e33ec803a371
 ---> 97d0d4785341
Step 9/15 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 89127b3e0759
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release [3457 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [985 kB]
Ign:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:12 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [564 B]
Get:13 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [564 B]
Get:14 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [819 B]
Get:15 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [833 B]
Get:16 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 Packages [10.1 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [589 kB]
Get:19 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [234 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [6281 B]
Get:23 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [69.2 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1363 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [993 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [19.3 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [7942 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [8807 B]
Fetched 16.5 MB in 3s (4437 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 89127b3e0759
 ---> 40e17fc965f5
Step 10/15 : RUN apt-get install libcurl3
 ---> Running in e8948beba790
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 186 kB of archives.
After this operation, 565 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcurl3 amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14 [186 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 186 kB in 0s (1042 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 12586 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl3_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Removing intermediate container e8948beba790
 ---> 61cba7cc1107
Step 11/15 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 5d705749b377
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release
Hit:11 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 5d705749b377
 ---> 587c1ad10364
Step 12/15 : RUN apt-get install mongodb-org
 ---> Running in 870304e0a384
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
  tzdata
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools tzdata
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 272 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install mongodb-org' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The only problem I error msg I see in the last line, which does not expplain mauch why the installation is not successful. Moreover, the following prompt does not give me any chance to type `Y`.

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, bitnami has a public available MongoDB image at `bitnami/mongodb:latest`

Comment: While @jstuartmilne's answer should get you through this error message, you should be aware that commands like `systemctl` broadly just don't work in Docker, and a Docker image never contains a running server.  Generally best practice is to run your database as a separate container, and the Docker Hub [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) image is a fine starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include the `-y` option like this:

```
apt-get install -y libcurl3

apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

or equivelent:

```
apt-get install --yes libcurl3

apt-get install --yes mongodb-org
```